# Flash / AS3: Load external swf *with animation*

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, loader

i load three external swf files into my flash movie, here's the code:

```
import flash.display.*

var screens:Array = new Array(
    'screens/left.swf',
    'screens/center.swf',
    'screens/right.swf'
);

var loaders:Array = new Array();

function complete_listener(event:Event):void {
    event.target.content.width  = 341;
    event.target.content.scaleY = event.target.content.scaleX;
}

for (var i=0; i<screens.length; i++) {
    loaders[i] = new Loader();
    loaders[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete_listener);
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(screens[i]);
    loaders[i].load(url);
    loaders[i].x = 341 * i;
    loaders[i].y = 0;
    addChild(loaders[i]);
}
```

everything works just fine with my three dummy swf's, but when i try to load an swf file that uses some kind of animation (for example a motion tween), the swf isn't displayed any more... is there a way around this? thank you!

Comment: Are these animations directly embedded in the loaded SWFs or are they in turn loaded from some other SWF?

Comment: They are directly embedded in the loaded SWFs. Actually you _can_ see the first frame (i guess) flash up every few seconds, really strange…

Comment: May be those animations might be crashing the loaded SWF due to some reason like accessing `stage` property from constructor (or before they're actually added to stage) - do you have access to the code of those animations? Make sure you're testing on a debug version of Flash player - this way you'll come to know what kind of error/exception is thrown

Comment: I think the problem is, that the background color of the stage is not shown when loading an external swf. do i really have to draw a rectangle with the same color in the background of the external swf or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Well I can not understand your problem properly.. But I will advise you one think that put `stop()` on all three swfs which you are gonna load. Then when they are loaded, you can start your animation then.

```
function complete_listener(event:Event):void 
{
    event.target.content.width  = 341;
    event.target.content.scaleY = event.target.content.scaleX; 
    var myLoadedSWF:MovieClip =event.target.content as MovieClip;
    myLoadedSWF.play();
}
```

Try this...